# Postgres - get records between two dates with a step/resolution

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM price_events 
WHERE code='BCI.AX' AND date BETWEEN (now() - interval '1 month') AND now() 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

This might return me hundreds of rows. I want to distill this down to say, 10 rows, evenly distributed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "eventy distributed" in what way?

Comment: I guess reasonable spaced. I.e. not all the entries clumped towards one date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a row number trick to identify records which occur every `n` steps, say 10 steps.  We can check if the row number be a multiple of the step size, and, if so, then retain that record.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM price_events 
    WHERE code='BCI.AX' AND date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month') AND NOW()
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn % ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) / 10) = 0
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This mostly works, but the result length is random, depending how many rows in the total set.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Can you be more specific?  My logic (I think) says to retain the ten records which fall on multiples of the total count divided by 10.  What are you actually seeing?

Comment: Well running the query above on my data set, I receive 15 rows back, not 10. If increase the time period to 1 year (instead of 1 month) I receive back 10.

Comment: I don't know your data, but a temporary fix would be to add `LIMIT 10` to the query, though this shouldn't be necessarym

Answer (score 1):

You can take a random sample by doing:

```
SELECT pe.*
FROM price_events  pe
WHERE code = 'BCI.AX' AND date BETWEEN (now() - interval '1 month') AND now() 
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 10;
```

That is often good enough for most purposes.  If you want to divide the data into  groups and choose one from each group, you can use `ntile()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (nt) pe.*
FROM (SELECT pe.*,
             NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY date) as nt -- speculating that you want date
      FROM price_events  pe
      WHERE code = 'BCI.AX' AND date BETWEEN (now() - interval '1 month') AND now() 
     ) pe
ORDER BY nt DESC;
```

What you may really want is the first record and then evenly spaced records .  That is more like this:

```
select pe.*
from (select pe.*,
             count(*) over () as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from price_events  pe
      where code = 'BCI.AX' and date between (now() - interval '1 month') and now() 
      ) pe
where seqnum in 1 or
      (seqnum % floor(cnt / 9)) = 0;
```

This gets more complicated if you want the first, last, and evenly spaced records in-between.  But one of the previous approaches will probably work for you.